# How to set the page numbers displayed in a GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pager

I have a gridview with a pager. The pager displays blocks of 10 page numbers (1...10, 11...20 etc.).

What I'm trying to achieve is that when the user clicks on a page number, the numbers in the pager will re-align so that the selected page will be in the middle of the list.
For example: If a user selects page 10, the numbers in the pager will be:

6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

Currently, it displays:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

And the only way for the user to reach page 11 is to click on the 3 dots (...).

How can that be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article explaining how you can customize the gridview's page, http://kikosantos.net/tech/2006/05/custom-paging-in-gridview-control/. From here, you should be able to customize the paging template to make the changes you desire.

Another example of custom paging: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/gridview/Custom-GridView-with-Paging-and-Filtering.aspx

And one more: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=339